# Digital Image Processing - Contemporary Research Topics

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, optimization

I need to propose a masters degree topic, and I'd like it to be in digital image processing. What are currently relevant topics in this area?

I suppose that I'm looking for some kind of optimization, either in hardware (like parallel processor architecture for image processing maybe) or software (image processing alogrithms optimization of some sort, maybe even in signal processing domain).

I'm leaning towards a software topic, because I think I can manage mathematics and algorithms better than computer engineering, compared to other people I guess.

Please suggest some contemporary topics and areas you believe are suitable for possible optimization, that could be achieved in a masters program :)

Comment: See these topics: http://www.di.ens.fr/~mallat/papiers/CRM-Mallat-Course1.pdf

Comment: @Deniz This looks interesting, thanks! Heavy maths though, will need some time to figure out what's going on :)

Comment: once you get the ideas of Fourier theory and with some linear algebra, you can manage it :) Of course, wavelets and those things have heavy theory but one can use them without delving into much theory.